# Pearl et al. (2016) definition of cause: circular?; how to improve?

Tags: causality, definition

Pearl et al. ["Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer"](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Causal+Inference+in+Statistics%3A+A+Primer-p-9781119186847) (2016) p. 26 provides the following definitions of *direct cause* and *cause*:

> A variable $X$ is a *direct cause* of a variable $Y$ if $X$ appears in
>   the function that assigns $Y$’s value. $X$ is a *cause* of $Y$ if it
>   is a direct cause of $Y$, or of any cause of $Y$.

It seems to me the definition of *cause* is circular (and thus essentially invalid) as it refers back to itself within the definition. Am I misunderstanding it? If not, how could the definition be improved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not circular, it's just recursive. It makes the functional programmer in me smile.

Note that this is actually two definitions - that of a *direct* cause, and then the more generic definition of (*any kind of*) cause, using the former as the boundary condition.

It's quite similar to how the set-theoretic definition of natural numbers, if you're familiar with that - there's the base case (empty set for 0 in numbers, direct cause for general causality), and then the recursive part (e.g. 1 is a **set of empty sets**, and a level-1 generalized cause is **the direct cause *of a direct cause* of Y)**.

Comment: I was suspecting something like that, but it is still hard to wrap my head around it... How do I verify whether $X$ is a cause of $Y$ in cases when it is not a direct cause? In such cases, I have to verify that $X$ is a direct cause of a cause of $Y$. But the definition of a cause is not explicit (it is recursive). Could you help me further?

Comment: Y as direct cause of Z: Z = f(Y, u1). X as direct cause of Y: Y = g(X, u2). X as cause of Z: Z = f(g(X, u2), u1), where the 'u's are sets of various other causal factors we're not interested in. If you can only observe X and Z, you may or may not be able to identify causal effects. If you do have Y, it's Bayes and chain rule time. This is a very TL;DR version, you really do need a proper book to cover everything.

Comment: I think I got it. I took a walk (before seeing your last comment), and it fell into places. Thank you for the answer!